# How to set a UILabel in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewcell

I have an app with a UIViewController with a UICollectionView IBOutlet in it.

[image: MyCustomCell Outlet connected]
[image: MyCustomCell ReuseID]
[image: MyCustomCell Class Identity]

The cell in the UICollectionView is MyCustomCell and has this method setting its UILabel:

```
-(void)setCellLabel:(NSString *)value{
    NSLog(@"settinglabel");
    cellLabel.text = @"hardcode"; //added for testing purposes
}
```

The cell has the property Class type identifying it as MyCustomCell in storyboard and its dequeue identifier as well.  The UIViewController adopts the datasource and delegate protocols.  The IBOutlet UILabel has its cellLabel outlet connected to the storyboard.  The methods are defined as:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.restNames = @[@"Orange",@"Naranja",@"Narnia"];

    [self.collectionView registerClass:[MyCustomCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCustomCellID"];

}
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    NSLog(@"%d",[self.restNames count]);
    return [self.restNames count];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    MyCustomCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


    [cell setCellLabel:@"hi"];
    NSLog(@"fitsname %@",[self.restNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);


    return cell;
}
```

I get three cells drawn in my tableview, corresponding to the 3 objects in my array.  The array simply contains string objects which I was setting directly by objectAtIndexPath but I decided to set it directly to @"hi" since it wasn't working.  I even changed the value used in setCellLabel method to a hardcoded value and I keep get just the "Label" default string in each cell.

Why isnt the cellLabel being set properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have your cellLabel outlet set in interface builder?

You should have something like this in your cell's .h file:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cellLabel;
```

then later you really just need to do this:

```
cell.cellLabel.text = @"";
```

Comment: yup...its connected to the UICollectionViewCell label

Comment: Are you calling [self.collectionView registerClass:[MyCustomCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier] again? If you are using a storyboard you don't want to call this. It will overwrite what you have in your storyboard.

Comment: I removed the line since I am using storyboard but I just get the default "Label" text.  With the line I get the blank cell, which is expected I guess.  The issue is that the label is not being set from default LABEL to my value.

Comment: Well you will need to dig a bit deeper. Does cellLabel == nil when you  call setCellLabel? Also you should probably be using self.cellLabel

Comment: Patrick, thx, I had IBOutlet UILabel as an ivar, so i set it as a property. Now I use self.cellLabel.text = @"string" instead of just cellLabel.text = ... However, I added an if test for cell.cellLabel == nil in cellForItemAtIndexPath and it does log as nil.

Comment: you need to synthesize your property if you haven't

Comment: since cell.cellLabel == nil something isn't set up right. I have updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Patrick, I do have a nonatomic, strong property. No need to synthesize @tiguero. I commented out the setCellLabel setter in MyCustomCell and its working. I just noticed xcode5dp4 is giving me a warning it wasnt before. `type of property cellLabel doesnt match accessor  setCellLabel`

Comment: @marciokoko no: the fact that you are using a strong property has nothing to do with the fact you don't need to synthesize. You should synthesize your property if you haven't define your getter/setter explicitly.

Comment: do you have another property called label?

Comment: @PatrickTescher I had to comment out my custom setter for cellLabel and it worked fine after that.  thx!

Answer (score 5):

When you're using Storyboard, the default template is wrong, because it uses the line

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionView class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

*But* the storyboard already registered it. So basically this is what you have to do to create a custom, storyboard based `UICollectionView` :

1. Create your `UICollectionViewController` subclass
2. Click&drag a `UICollectionViewController` to the storyboard and change the configuration as you want
3. Create a `UICollectionViewCell` subclass
4. Set the cell class in the storyboard, set it's reuse identifier ctrl-drag the needed outlets
5. Remove the `[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier];`
6. Set the static reuse identifier in the `UICollectionView` subclass

Answer (score 0):

You have probably forgotten to tell your `UICollectionView` what class it’s supposed to use to create cells. This is done with the following line of code:

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[MyCustomCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier];
```

You can set this at the end of the viewDidLoad of your controller.

Comment: If you use Interface Builder you don't need to run this command.

Comment: Im using storyboard...ive got this line in my viewDidLoad

Comment: did u check if the setCellLabel is called?

Comment: also check your outlet are all set correctly (UICollectionView and UICollectionViewCell)

Comment: I updated the question. The outlet is connected and setCellLabel is being called, I just inserted a NSLog and it logs fine.

Comment: ok so from your edit you shouldn't need the line of code i mentioned here as you did it on IB

Comment: add a [cell setNeedsDisplay] after [cell setCellLabel:@"hi"]; maybe? should force the cell to be redrawn

Comment: I took out my [ registerClass line, and now it works