# iOS: Storyboard CollectionView segue not being triggered

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uistoryboard

I have a UICollectionView controller embedded inside a navigation controller.  The collectionView lists projects and each cell is supposed to segue to a ProjectDetail screen.

I simply cannot get the segue to trigger.  If I simply drop a button on the nav bar and hook up a segue to the detail, it works.  But triggering from my CollectionView cell doesn't.

Here is what the storyboard looks like: http://cl.ly/RfcM  I do have a segue hooked up from the CollectionViewCell to the ProjectDetailViewController

Here's the relevant code inside my ProjectDetailViewController:

```
@interface ProjectCollectionViewController () {
    NSArray *feedPhotos;
    Projects *projects;
}

@end

@implementation ProjectCollectionViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[FeedViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    [self loadData];

}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"selected %d", indexPath.row);
    Project *project = [projects getProject:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"project = %@", project);
}

- (void)loadData {

    [self.projectLoader loadFeed:self.username
                       onSuccess:^(Projects *loadedProjects) {
                           NSLog(@"view did load on success :  projects %@", loadedProjects);
                           projects = loadedProjects;

                           [self.collectionView reloadData];
                       }
                       onFailure:^(NSError *error) {
                           [self handleConnectionError:error];
                       }];
}


- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   return projects.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *identifier = @"cell";
    FeedViewCell *cell = (FeedViewCell *) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];
    UIImageView *cellImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    Project *project = [projects getProject:indexPath.row];
    NSString *imageUrl = [project coverPhotoUrl:200 forHeight:200];
    NSLog(@"imageurl =>%@", imageUrl);
    if (imageUrl) {
        [cellImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl]];
    }
    [cell addSubview:cellImageView];
    cell.imageView = cellImageView;
    return cell;
}
```

I'm guessing the problem is somewhere in how I'm hooking up the Cells to the CollectionView.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You cannot create segues directly from cells in a storyboard because the collectionview is populated dynamically through the data source. You should use the [`collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UICollectionViewDelegate/collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:) and perform the segue programatically using [`performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:). Something like this:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegueIdentifier" sender:self];
}
```

where `MySegueIdentifier` is the identifier of the segue defined in storyboard.

Comment: So can someone tell me what has changed? Because here http://www.appcoda.com/ios-collection-view-tutorial/ we can see clearly that the connection is made in `Storyboard` and it works.

Comment: This answer is outdated. Definitely, you can create segues directly in Storyboard.

Answer (score 3):

TLDR:  FOR A STORYBOARD, do not call registerClass:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:.  It overrides what the storyboard sets up for the cell (including how segues are handled):
[How to set a UILabel in UICollectionViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17957819/how-to-set-a-uilabel-in-uicollectionviewcell)

Brief setup

- Used a storyboard
- Created a new collection view controller using the Xcode template,
  setting it as a subclass of UICollectionViewController.
- Initially used the default UICollectionViewCell, adding a UILabel
  programmatically.

The generated UICollectionViewController code registered the cell in viewDidLoad:

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
```

**First Issue:**
The prepareForSegue:sender: event was not firing, which brought me to this answer .
I implemented the UICollectionViewDelegate and collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath: event, then called the segue programmatically.
This fixed my first issue.

**Second Issue:**  I switched to a custom cell containing one label.  After hooking everything up, the cell label was not displaying.
After some digging, I found a solution contained in the link at the top of my answer.

**Third Issue  and Solution:**  I removed the registerClass:forCellWithReuseIdentifier: line.  When I ran my app, the label appeared correctly, but when I tapped a cell, it called the prepareForSegue:sender event twice.  By removing the registerClass:forCellWithReuseIdentifier line, the cell was processing cell touches directly, without the need of the delegate method. This is how I expected the storyboard to work.  I deleted the collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath: event, which resolved the double-firing of prepareForSegue:sender:.  **If you are using a storyboard, do not register the cell class.  It overwrites what storyboard sets up.**

Comment: @Claude Do you know why using collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndePath: overwrites what storyboard sets up?

Answer (score 2):

Have you made your CollectionView Cell's connection in `Triggered Segues` on `selection`?

[image]

You can also trigger a segue programatically using
 `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueIdentifier" sender:nil]`

in

`- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Answer (score 0):

Equivalent Swift code for similar question.

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier(@"TargetSegway", sender: self)
}
```

Make sure, in case if your cell has other overlapping views, "*User Interaction Enabled*" is **unchecked** (you can find this option, under attribute inspector View/Interaction). Otherwise, your Tap Gesture is consumed by the overlapping view, **didSelectItemAtIndexPath** may not be called.