# Pass data from UICollectionView in Segue

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uistoryboardsegue

I have a UICollectionView that segues to a Detail VC. The segue goes from custom cell to the detail.

I read here [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19070791/ios-storyboard-collectionview-segue-not-being-triggered/) that you can't use `prepareForSegue`that you must use `performSegue`in `didSelectItem`

The issue is, I need to pass data. I tried using `prepareForSegue` anyways, but the cells are now not selectable. Ideas?

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detailSegue"]) {
        LPDiaryDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForCell:sender];
        LocationImage *image = self.savedItems[indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"collectionView imageview %@", destViewController.thumbnailView);

        destViewController.usernameLabel.text = [image valueForKeyPath:@"user.username"];
        destViewController.locationLabel.text = [image valueForKeyPath:@"location.name"];
        destViewController.captionString = image.caption;

    }
}
```

Then I tried this with `performSegue` in `didSelectItem` and I created a method `createLocationImage`to call the detail VC to make a LocationImage in it's implementation, but the `createLocationImage` never gets called

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    LocationImage *testImage = (LocationImage*)self.savedItems[indexPath.row];
    [self.diaryDetailVC createLocationImage:testImage];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detailSegue" sender:self];
}
```

Comment: please put some code here.

Comment: What you have tried? can you show `prepareForSegue` method?

Comment: instead you can use custom navigation!

Comment: added requested code