# Unexpectedly found nil for optional value - which is not nil after optional chaining

Tags: swift, uiimage, uicollectionview

I've an array of images in CoreData, which is fetched and used in the Master View Controller and passed to the Detailed View Controller and again to a Container View Controller. The images are successfully shown in the Master and Detail controllers, but not the Container View Controller.

Within the Container View Controller, I am using conditional binding to unwrap the image in cellForItemAtIndexPath.

[image]

In the debugger, print("did actually: (images.count)") on load shows I've an image in the array, and imageForCell is not nil - it is a UIImage - BUT, I still get unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value...

[image]

Comment: You checked cell and cell.cellImageView to not be nil I hope?

Comment: Ah ha - the cellImageView is nil! What do I need to do to instantiate the view?

Comment: My cell is a custom cell, but other than an outlet for the cellImageView, it is empty. I tried a convenience init and otherways to initialize the outlet to UIImageView(), but cell.cellImageView stays nil!

Comment: This will differ depending on if you're using a storyboard or a nib. My advice is to google it :)

Comment: I have googled this, many times, but I can't find a solution that works. The collection view is in the storyboard. However, in the storyboard, it is connected / seguing to another View Controller. The collection view is instantiated, but nothing seems to instantiate the image view reference outlet within my custom UICollectionViewCell. I've tried registering the class in didLoad, convenience inits of the image view within the custom cell class or in the cellForItem method.

Comment: Are you registering the cell to the collection view yourself?

Comment: Yes - in viewDidLoad - self.collectionView!.registerClass(PhotoCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell").

Comment: Does it work when you remove that line? Or is the cell nil now?

Comment: Yes! It works without registering the cell?!? If you could pleeeease explain when to use registerClass forCellWithReuseIdentifier, I'd give you the answer, and I'm sure others would find it helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to give the answer to this question, first always check what is nil. You assumed the value you unwrapped was nil, but your view was actually nil.

A tip: use the gaurd statement. Inside the guard statement you have to specify what your code has to do in an error situation. After the guard statement, you can use the values that you unwrapped. Your current code just shows an empty cell without any messages when your image is nil. If it would not show an image, you would not know what went wrong.

Personally I like to check every possible optional in my methods. This makes methods annoyingly large, but prevents errors. I also like to specify the type of the object, but that is entirely up to you. For me it's mostly the difference between "UIImage" and "UIImage?". In your situation the UIImage might still be nil.

To continue to your next question, why it still wasn't working. So I looked around at how a UICollectionView would initialize its cells when loaded from the storyboard. People said that when manually using registerClass in those scenario's it would overwrite the view loaded from the storyboard. See: [How to set a UILabel in UICollectionViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17957819/how-to-set-a-uilabel-in-uicollectionviewcell). I asked you to remove it, to confirm my suspicions.

I'm assuming you only need to use registerClass when not loading a view from a storyboard or nib/xib.